# How to replace characters in list item as keys with values in dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, data-structures

I'm trying to do something like this:

**My input**:

```
predefined_list=['gross pay']
predefined_dict={'a':'o','o':'a','g':'c','c':'g'}
```

**Desired**

```
output: ['gross pay', 'gross poy', 'grass pay', 'crass pay', cross pay, crass poy]
```

and other several combinations.

i tried:

```
predefined_list=['gross pay']
predefined_dict={'a':'o','o':'a','g':'c','c':'g'}

i=0;
for key,value in predefined_dict.items():
    final=predefined_list[i].replace(key,value)
    i+=1
    if final not in predefined_list:
        predefined_list.append(final)
print(predefined_list)
```

Comment: why are you reassigning `prefefined_dict` inside the loop?

Comment: updated, my mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way

```
for key, value in predefined_dict.items():
        for  word in predefined_list:
            for n in range(word.count(key)):
                final = word.replace(key,value,n+1)
                if final not in predefined_list:
                    predefined_list.append(final)
```

Output:

```
>>> predefined_list

['gross pay', 'gross poy', 'grass pay', 'grass poy', 'cross pay', 'cross poy', 'crass pay', 'crass poy']
```

Comment: crass poy & grass poy is missing in it

Comment: My mistake, the whole loop with n was to loop through and do `.replace(key,value,n+1)` and I forgot to put it there

Answer (score 1):

Just replace your string by iterating through your dictionary's keys and values

```
modified_list = [predefined_list[0].replace(k,v) for k,v in predefined_dict.items()]
```

Output

```
['gross poy', 'grass pay', 'cross pay', 'gross pay']
```

Similarly

```
predefined_list = ['pay gross', 'gross pay']
modified_dict = {list_k: [list_k.replace(k,v) for k,v in predefined_dict.items()]
                 for list_k in predefined_list}
```

Output

```
{'gross pay': ['gross poy', 'grass pay', 'cross pay', 'gross pay'],
 'pay gross': ['poy gross', 'pay grass', 'pay cross', 'pay gross']}
```